# Images in cell are changing everytime when tableview is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the below code whenever I am scrolling the tableview, images in each cell are changing, which shouldn't happen. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UserDetails *userDetails = [arrUserDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
__weak TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[_tableViewUsername dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.userName.text = userDetails.userName;
   [self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock: ^ {  
    NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:userDetails.userImageURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL options:nil error:&error];
    UIImage *image = nil;
    if (cell.tag == indexPath.row)
    {
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^ {
            cell.customImageView.image = image;
            cell.customImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Learn more about how `UITableView` works mate. Cells are dequeued and reused all the while. That's why you are seeing images go to what you think are wrong cells but for iOS they are the right ones because `cell.tag==indexPath.row`. You need more solid reference than tag.

Comment: Use a custom cell and define it's properties like the name label and image view. That will keep a solid reference to which cell is which and solve the issue which is caused by your current code i.e. creation of UIElements every time the delegate method gets called.

Comment: @muku is correct - you aren't setting a default image or at least clearing the old image while you load the new one.  Also consider using something like SDWebImage to provide caching for better performance

Comment: Before setting image to cell.customImageView you should clear previous image like cell.customImageView.image = nil.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UserDetails *userDetails = [arrUserDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
__weak TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[_tableViewUsername dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.userName.text = userDetails.userName;

//Add Default placeholder
cell.customImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

   [self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock: ^ {  
    NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:userDetails.userImageURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL options:nil error:&error];
    UIImage *image = nil;
    if (cell.tag == indexPath.row)
    {
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^ {
            cell.customImageView.image = image;
            cell.customImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }];
    }
}];
```

Add Default placeholder for image before loading it from url,As cells are being reused it takes the previous image

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage.framework to load image

```
[cell.customImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userDetails.userImageURL] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
      if (image) {
          [cell.customImageView setImage:image];
      }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Afnetworking class for this .

Simply import **#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"**

And use this line:-

**[cell.imgProfile setImageWithURL:imgurl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];**

Imgurl is the image Url which you are getting from response